# PHP get the file name without the parameters

Tags: php

I have these urls

```
something2/something3/fileName.php

something2/something3/fileName.php?para=someting&param2=something2
```

I want to get the `fileName` without the `.php` extension and without the paramets,

**note**: not all the urls have parameters.

#### What I have tried:

```
$phpFileName = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");//without .php extension
```

that works only when there are no parameters in the urls, but when there are parameters in the url, i got like this:

```
fileName.php?parm=something&param=something
```

how can I remove these parameters please and get just the `fileName` ?

thanks

Comment: [pathinfo()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) -> `["filename"]`

Answer (score 2):

Well if the code is in the file itself you can use...

`$phpFileName = basename(__FILE__, ".php");`

The `__FILE__` is a magic constant to the current file being executed.

Otherwise just remove the query string using `explode` first...

```
$qs = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$phpFileName = basename($qs[0], ".php");
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the path from the URL first with `parse_url`:

```
$phpFileName = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_PATH), ".php");
```

You could also look at `pathinfo`.